# How to request reload for TYPO3 extension field using mask

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions, tx-mask

How do I request a reload for a TYPO3 extension field that is the trigger for a display condition of an other field in the `mask.json`.

```json
    "tx_mask_foobarfield": {
        "config": {
            "type": "select",
            "renderType": "selectSingle",
            "size": "",
            "default": "foo",
            "onChange" : "reload",
            "items": [
                [
                    "Foo",
                    "foo"
                ],
                [
                    "Bar",
                    "bar"
                ]
            ],
            "foreign_table": "",
            "foreign_table_where": "",
            "fileFolder": "",
            "fileFolder_extList": "",
            "fileFolder_recursions": "",
            "maxitems": "",
            "autoSizeMax": ""
        },
        "exclude": "0",
        "key": "some_key"
    },
```

I tried a couple of things but all references I could find tell me just about the way to do it in TCA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the `"onChange": "reload"` on the wrong level.
From [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/Columns/Index.html?highlight=onchange#onchange) it should be a direct successor of the fieldname (sibling to `config`)